# Not getting proper values in jFrame

Tags: java

I have made a program to add matrices and for that i made 3 jframe i accepted some values in jFrame1 and now I want to show all the Values in jFrame 3 but when i do so it shows an error

In my jFrame1 I declared an array and then coded under a button

```
int a=Integer.parseInt(txt1.getText());
int b=Integer.parseInt(txt2.getText());
int c=Integer.parseInt(txt3.getText());
int d=Integer.parseInt(txt4.getText());
int e=Integer.parseInt(txt5.getText());
int f=Integer.parseInt(txt6.getText());
int g=Integer.parseInt(txt7.getText());
int h=Integer.parseInt(txt8.getText());
int i=Integer.parseInt(txt9.getText());

ar[0]=a;
ar[1]=b;
ar[2]=c;
ar[3]=d;
ar[4]=e;
ar[5]=f;
ar[6]=g;
ar[7]=h;
ar[8]=i;
```

and in jFrame 2 i called for values

```
Matrices m = new Matrices();
ctxt1=setText(""+m.ar[0]);
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please look at post an [MCVE] for help quicker. The question appears to be missing some relevant code for the JFrame. Also, what is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting??And is Matrices a separate class or is it extending JFrame?

Comment: Need to know more, need complete code. What are the values of "txt-xyz", how is defined "ar".. need classes of the definition and usage.

Comment: Side note: You don't actually need the variables `a` through `i`. Just use `ar[0]=Integer.parseInt(txt1.getText())` etc., and better yet, don't have a `txt1` through `txt9`, but rather an array of components `txt[0]` through `txt[8]`, and then you'll be able to use a loop for this.